# Multiple notLike won´t work

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I got the following sequelize query snippet where i like to do a multiple notLike query:

```
article
    .findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        NAME: {
          $like: '%'+req.body.search+'%'
        },
        ITEM_NUMBER: {
               $notLike: 'MF%',
               $notLike: 'OLS%',
               $notLike: 'MV%',
               $notLike: 'MD%',
               $notLike: 'AE%'
         },
         PRICE: {
           $gt: 0
         },
         BLOCKED_FROM: {
           $or: {
             $gt: new Date(),
             $eq: null
           }
         }
       },
      limit: 20
     })
    .then(function(result) {
      res.json(result.rows);
      //res.json(result.count);
      console.log(result.count);
      console.log(result.rows);
    });
```

The problem is that the where part for ITEM_NUMBER only seams to take the last notLike line ($notLike: 'AE%') in the query. The resulting query output shows:

> SELECT TOP 20 [NAME], [ITEM_NUMBER], [PRICE], [BLOCKED_FROM] FROM [ARTIKEL] AS [ARTIKEL] WHERE [ARTIKEL].[NAME] LIKE N'%testname%' AND [ARTIKEL].[ITEM_NUMBER] NOT LIKE N'AE%' AND [ARTIKEL].[PRICE] > 0 AND ([ARTIKEL].[BLOCKED_FROM] > N'2016-12-28 17:05:58.750' OR [ARTIKEL].[BLOCKED_FROM] IS NULL);

The query should contain all %notLike parameters. Any idea what´s wrong?
Thx
Ingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
    ...
    ITEM_NUMBER: {
        $or: [{
           $notLike: 'MF%'
        }, {
           $notLike: 'OLS%'
        }, {
           $notLike: 'MV%'
        }, {
           $notLike: 'MD%'
        }, {
           $notLike: 'AE%'
        }]
    },
    ...
```

Comment: That´s funny. It works. I´ve tried that before without the starting bracket after the or operator. I only took the curly bracket as also shown in the docs in the  [Combinations Chapter](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/) where the first or operator example is without square brackets...Thx for that!

Comment: glad to help @Inge

Answer (score 0):

When use the same key in array only take one of then, try replacing like this:

```
article
.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    NAME: {
      $like: '%'+req.body.search+'%'
    },
    ITEM_NUMBER: {
           $notLike: { $any: ['MF%','OLS%','MV%','MD%','AE%']}
     },
     PRICE: {
       $gt: 0
     },
     BLOCKED_FROM: {
       $or: {
         $gt: new Date(),
         $eq: null
       }
     }
   },
  limit: 20
 })
.then(function(result) {
  res.json(result.rows);
  //res.json(result.count);
  console.log(result.count);
  console.log(result.rows);
});
```

[Operator of where](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/?highlight=$notLike) http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/?highlight=$notLike

Comment: I´ve already tried that but then it throws an error  `Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ANY'`. Any idea?

Comment: And as im not wrong ANY is only for PG? I´m on mssql-server.